# What does the regex pattern 'pL' do?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

There is a common Regex used to slugify urls `~[^\\pL\d]+~u` but what does the`\\pL` in the first `preg_replace()` mean?

Here are some examples:

- [How can I  replace ":" with "/" in slugify function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577041/how-can-i-replace-with-in-slugify-function)
- http://snipplr.com/view/22741/slugify-a-string-in-php/
- http://sourcecookbook.com/en/recipes/8/function-to-slugify-strings-in-php
- http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/471380/php-slugify-two-variables-together

Comment: Reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category

Comment: You can't find them? Did you look? Googling `regex \\pL` leads directly to this: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`\\pL` is a Unicode property shortcut. It can also be written as as`\p{L}` or `\p{Letter}`. It matches any kind of letter from any language.

Answer (score 6):

`\\pL` is a shorthand for `\\p{L}`

[reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category)

> In addition to the standard notation, \p{L}, **Java, PHP, Perl, PCRE and the JGsoft engine allow you to use the shorthand \pL**. The shorthand only works with single-letter Unicode properties. \pLl is not the equivalent of \p{Ll}. It is the equivalent of \p{L}l which matches Al or àl or any Unicode letter followed by a literal l.